# Latex: right square bracket

Tags: math, latex, fractions

I have one strange trouble with latex. Needed square bracket only from right and for net example it working:

```
$\left[ 
  \begin{gathered} 
    \left\{ 
      \begin{gathered} 
        x^2 - 6 \geqslant x, \hfill 
        \\ 
        5x < 1 \hfill 
        \\ 
      \end{gathered} 
    \right. \hfill 
    \\ 
    \left\{ 
      \begin{gathered} 
        x^3 - 8 < 0, \hfill 
        \\ 
        x^2 - 7x < 0. \hfill 
        \\ 
      \end{gathered} 
    \right. \hfill 
    \\ 
  \end{gathered} 
\right.$
```

[Result](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%24%5Cleft%5B%20%5Cbegin%7Bgathered%7D%20%5Cleft%5C%7B%20%5Cbegin%7Bgathered%7D%20x%5E2%20-%206%20%5Cgeqslant%20x%2C%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%205x%20%3C%201%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bgathered%7D%20%5Cright.%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%20%5Cleft%5C%7B%20%5Cbegin%7Bgathered%7D%20x%5E3%20-%208%20%3C%200%2C%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%20x%5E2%20-%207x%20%3C%200.%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bgathered%7D%20%5Cright.%20%5Chfill%20%5C%5C%20%5Cend%7Bgathered%7D%20%5Cright.%24)

But for example with `\frac{x}{a}` not worked!

```
$\left[ 
  \begin{gathered} 
    \frac{2}{3} > 1;
  \\ 
    \frac{2}{3} > 1;
  \end{gathered} 
\right.$
```

How get the square bracket for expression with fractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That both works for me. Maybe you forgot to `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: When using just that online equation editor, remove the `$` and don't try to load any package – then it will be working. Keep in mind that you cannot compile a complete latex document by this.